# in Atom-editor how can I save a regex find/replace to use later?

Tags: atom-editor

Coming from vim, I could add a pre-defined find/replace by using the 'command' keyword in the .vimrc file and give it a command name.

What would be the equivalent on atom, to be able to, essentially, define a find/replace regex and save it as a new command to call up whenever needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://atom.io/packages/replacing-pattern-collection

replacing-pattern-collection package

This package helps using find-and-replace.
If you often use same complex pattern in find-and-replace, this package is helpful.
This package save patterns to file, and load patterns from file.

See package docs for usage help.